# All data erased when reboot of edit the program

Tags: sql-server, database

Each time the program is run, or when the program is edited and run, the SQL Server database (`.mdf` file) is cleared and only the data given later is seen. All old data is cleared.

I made this program in Visual Studio 2010. How to fix this? How can the data be permanently saved to the SQL Server database?

Comment: Create a proper instance of SQL Server, and stop using the `AttachDbFile=....` approach in SQL Server Express.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that you are looking at the correct MDF file? When you run your program it will copy to a folder under `[ProjectFolder]/bin` - if you are running the Debug configuration it will be `[ProjectFolder]/bin/Debug/yourFile.mdf` and if you are running the Release configurations it will be `[ProjectFolder]/bin/Release/yourFile.mdf`. These are separate from the MDF file that is likely in the project root (`[ProjectFolder]`). If you are making changes when the program is running, it will be saved (assuming your code is correct) to one of the MDF files that exist under the `[ProjectFolder]/bin` folder.